# Recursive Header Inclusion Errors in C++

Tags: c++, header, include

I'm using two classes that depend on each other. However, when I compile the program I get a nonsensical exception description. I have reduced my code to show the error only when I include the `World.h` header file in the `Creature` header file. The exception is thrown before an opportunity to implement a forward declaration, or template. Also, preprocessor directives are not working in my case.

Creature header:

```
#ifndef __CREATURE_H
#define __CREATURE_H
#include "World.h"
    class Creature
    {
    public:
        //World *world; -- This class only needs a pointer to world. 
    };
#endif
```

World header:

```
#ifndef WORLD_H
#define WORLD_H
#include "Creature.h"
    class World
    {
    public:
        Creature** world;
    };
#endif
```

A Driver to complete the example:

```
#include "World.h"
int main()
{
    World world;
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2012's Exception message:

```
world.h(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
world.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I noticed in my minimal example that `Intellisense` will underline an inclusion and on hover show: "Include file .. includes itself". This doesn't happen in my larger project. However, commenting the include, uncommenting the instantiation of the other class, then compiling the project produces the same error.

Comment: If `Creature` only needs a pointer to `World`, you can use a forward declaration instead of #including world.h.

Comment: If you only need a pointer, than why are you including the definition? Use a forward-declaration instead: `class World;`. That's a good idea even if you have no recursive dependencies you need to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler "sees" `class Creature`, complete with its `World*`, before it sees `World`. This becomes obvious if we do the #including by hand:

```
#ifndef WORLD_H
#define WORLD_H

   //#include "Creature.h"
      #ifndef __CREATURE_H
      #define __CREATURE_H
      #include "World.h" // the #ifndef prevents this from expanding into anything interesting
      class Creature
      {
      public:
         World *world; // here's World! Except...it hasn't been declared or defined yet. 
      };
      #endif

   // finally we get to class World, but it's too late     
   class World
   {
   public:
      Creature** world;
   };
#endif
```

A simple solution is to forward-declare `World` instead of using reciprocal includes. e.g.:

```
#ifndef __CREATURE_H
#define __CREATURE_H
    class World; // instead of #include "World.h"

    class Creature
    {
    public:
        World *world;
    };
#endif
```

And based on the code you've shown, you can do the same thing with `Creature` in world.h (though you only need one of the two to solve the compile problem).

Comment: Perfect. You're a few minutes too late, or I would have deemed this the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a forward declaration.

In Creature.h change

```
#include "World.h"
```

to

```
class World;
```

Comment: Why? How does that fix it? What if there were no recursive inclusion anyway?

Comment: Yes. I can compile. But I'm having difficulty accessing methods of World in Creature, using the pointer? This condition: `if(world.getAt(row,element - 1).type == ENEMY)` produces "Expression must have class type."

Comment: Also, this: `if(world->getAt(row, element + 1).type == ENEMY)` produces: "Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed" ... Is this normal in this situation?

Comment: You can still include World.h inside Creature.cpp, that will allow your Creature methods to use the World class. You just can't put code that need to know what World is in Creature.h

Comment: @Deduplicator - I am not sure what you mean. If there were no recursive inclusions, then there wouldn't be a problem. Or were you asking me to expand my answer?

Comment: Yep, the first two really should be addressed in your answer to make it acceptable, the last would be a good thing to address as well.

Comment: Fair enough. I think dll's answer covers it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a declare problem. and it's not a good idea to have "#include" in your header file.

better way: (notice i use "#pragma once" instead of "#ifndef #define")

Creature.h

```
#pragma once
class World;
class Creature {.........}
```

World.h

```
#pragma once
class Creature;
class World {..........}
```

your any .cpp file

```
#include "World.h"
#include "Creature.h"
```

Comment: This will cause class redeclaration errors.

Comment: It's perfectly fine, and even *the right thing* to have includes in a header. It just should be the minimum needed, and forward-declarations are preferable.

Comment: @Giffyguy: "class redeclaration errors"? What's that?

Comment: @Deduplicator If you define class Foo with all its members, and then afterwards write `class Foo;` again (declaring the class again), the compiler will/should throw an error. Recursive headers with forward declarations can cause this.

Comment: @Giffyguy: Why should that be an error, instead of just useless repetition, as it is now?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend sending your preprocessor output to a file, and checking what the actual preprocessed code looks like.

To solve issues like this, I would create another header file with forward declarations (such as `declarations.h`), then include the forward declarations in each header where you define a class implementation.

The normal methods of keeping headers from being included more than once (`#ifndef`, `#pragma once`, etc.) will work flawlessly to prevent anything from being declared or defined more than once, while allowing both World and Creature to reference each other with pointers.

The key here is, the cpp file where the `main` function is defined, will need to include BOTH `World.h` and `Creature.h`